# How to properly escape tags in input text

Tags: php, escaping, htmlspecialchars, strip-tags

looks like ordinary question but could not find correct solution. lets say I have this form:

```
<form name="form" action="nextpage.php">
<input type="text" name="input_name" value="<?php echo $_POST['input_name'];?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

For example if I add "My input text >" as value of the input the nextpage.php is broken.
I tried to use for:`value="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST['input_name']);?>"` or 
:`value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['input_name']);?>"` but none of them works.. Why is that and how to avoid it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should sanitize your posted value for security, but that aside, php provides a function that automatically escapes special characters called addslahes http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php, save your post value to a variable using the addslashes function, then use the variable as your value.

Comment: addslashes and htmlentities did not help also !

Comment: Have you tried echoing out your post value to make sure something is actually being posted?

Comment: Yes, it posts My input text > but thanks to you and #error I fixed the problem, thanks!

Comment: Glad to see you fixed it, if addslashes worked, please mark my answer as helpful and correct.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
        $_POST['input_name']="ddd";  ?>
        <form name="form" method="POST" action="nextpage.php">
    <input type="text" name="input_name" value="<?php echo $_POST['input_name'];?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next"/>
    </form>
```

and in nextpage.php

```
<?php

$name=$_POST['input_name'];

echo $name;
```

Comment: I already tried on the top of  nextpage.php to escape it like this $_POST['input_name']=htmlspecialchars($_POST['input_name');
but it aint work

Comment: actualy $name=addslashes($_POST['input_name']); worked :), thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form name="form" action="nextpage.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="input_name" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['input_name'];?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Next"/>

</form>
```